# telling the cmd what version of python im using

Tags: django, python-3.x, cmd

IM trying to make a website with django and im following a tutorial that is telling me i need to tell my cmd prompt what version of python im using. this is the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FNQxxpM1yOs at the 10:46 mark he says to put C:/Python35/ python manage.py runserver. I am putting thi but it is not working. I am using version 3.7 so i replaced 35 with 37 but it is still not working. can someone please helps with this.

Comment: If your python is the only version installed to your system and its location is somewhere within the locations listed within the `%PATH%` variable; and your `%PATHEXT%` variable is unmodified, you should be able to use `python manage.py runserver` or `start python manage.py runserver`. If it isn't, you could use the fully qualified locations, i.e. `C:\PathTo\python.exe C:\Somewhere\manage.py runserver` or `Start C:\PathTo\python.exe C:\Somewhere\manage.py runserver`. If any of those locations have spaces in their names, you'll need to enclose those locations in doublequotes.

Comment: it keeps saying "not recognized as a cmdlet, function, script file or operable program"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's different depending on OS, but I'm on Linux and use `python3 manage.py runserver` since I have python 2 and 3 installed. Using just `python` tries to use python 2, which I'm guessing isn't the version of Django you installed. I also use `pip3` when I need to.

Comment: it keeps saying "not recognized as a cmdlet, function, script file or operable program"

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are on Windows, you can do `where python` in your shell (which is pretty similar to `which` command on Linux) to locate your python.

If you installed python correctly then python should be already in your $PATH, in this case, as suggested by @marsonfire, just run `python manage.py runserver` or `python3 manage.py runserver` in your project folder.

Comment: it keeps saying "not recognized as a cmdlet, function, script file or operable program"

Comment: @caleb282 which means python is not in your $PATH and you did not install python correctly. If you are having trouble with the python installer, try to use [choco](https://chocolatey.org/) to install python. After that you should be able to use `python` as a command. Note after you installed choco run `choco install python`.

Comment: i installed choco on my windows power shell and then tried to use the choco install python command, but it gave me an error saying 'choco' is not a recognized program.